# BlackBerry 6/7 Table Layout with ColSpan - Number Selection Widget

Tags: layout, blackberry

Trying to make a simple number clicker control for BlackBerry 6/7, like this:

[image]

At heart it's just a text field and two buttons, with a Manager to space them out.

I know about the unsupported add-on TableManager, but it doesn't support column scans. And, the notion of using deeply-nested Managers I find... disturbing.

And, this will come up multiple times, so I wanted a simple, reusable component.

So, I built a simple Manager to contain these three components, even allowing you to provide your own textfield or buttons for stylistic reasons.  The code is attached below. Obviously fancier than it needs to be but the work is all done in sublayout.

What actually happens is that the upper right of each of the 3 components appears in the correct place, but the 3 components are "shrink wrapped" to the minimum size needed to display their contents, ignoring the requested USE_ALL_WIDTH and USE_ALL_HEIGHT. This is probably a minor goofup, but how can I make these components actually USE ALL WIDTH and USE ALL HEIGHT? I have tried several variations on USE_ALL_* but not found the winning one yet. Of course any other improvements would also be welcome.

Thanks.

```
package layout;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.XYEdges;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.EditField;

/**
 * XXX BROKEN DO NOT USE YET - layout fail, components get shrink-wrapped.
 * 
 * NumberClicker Makes a layout with three components, like this:
 * <pre>
 * +-------------------+ +-------------------+
 * |                   | |          +        |
 * |         3         | |-------------------|
 * |                   | |-------------------|
 * |                   | |          -        |
 * |-------------------| |-------------------|
 * </pre>
 * Note that by default, the buttons are set to increment and decrement the number in the textfield!
 * @author Ian Darwin
 */
public class NumberClicker extends Manager {

    private static final long SUBCOMPONENT_STYLE = Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH;
    private static final long MANAGER_STYLE = Field.FIELD_HCENTER | Field.FIELD_VCENTER;

    final XYEdges MARGINS = new XYEdges(10,10,10,10);

    EditField number = new EditField(SUBCOMPONENT_STYLE);
    ButtonField plus = new ButtonField("+", SUBCOMPONENT_STYLE);
    ButtonField minus = new ButtonField("-", SUBCOMPONENT_STYLE);

    public NumberClicker() {
        this(MANAGER_STYLE);
    }
    public NumberClicker(long style) 
    {
        this(null, null, null, style);
    }

    /** Constructor allows you to provide your own three fields */
    public NumberClicker(EditField number, ButtonField plus, ButtonField minus) { 
        this(number, plus, minus, MANAGER_STYLE);
    }

    /** Constructor allows you to provide your own three fields ANd override style.
     * If any of the fields is null, the default value is used.
     */
    public NumberClicker(EditField number, ButtonField plus, ButtonField minus, long style) {
        super(style);
        if (number != null) {
            this.number = number;
        } else {
            this.number.setMargin(MARGINS); // set margins on our default, constructed above.
        }
        setValue(1);
        add(this.number); // Nulls allowed, so must be careful to use "this." throughout this method.

        if (plus != null) {
            this.plus = plus;
        } else {
            this.plus.setMargin(MARGINS);
        }
        add(this.plus);

        if (minus != null) {
            this.minus = minus;
        } else {
            this.minus.setMargin(MARGINS);
        }
        add(this.minus);

        this.plus.setRunnable(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                increment();
            }           
        });
        this.minus.setRunnable(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                decrement();
            }           
        });
    }

    public void increment() {
        number.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(number.getText().trim()) + 1));
    }

    public void decrement() {
        number.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(number.getText().trim()) - 1));
    }

    /** Return the integer value of the clicker. Do not call if you are re-using this as a three-component layout manager! */
    public int getValue() {
        return Integer.parseInt(number.getText().trim());
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        number.setText(Integer.toString(value));
    }

    /** 
     * Compute sizes and positions of subfields.
     * 
     * Required by Manager 
     */
    public void sublayout(int width, int height)  {
        int layoutWidth = width;
        int layoutHeight = Math.min(height, Display.getHeight()); // no scrolling here
System.err.println("Display:" + Display.getWidth() + "x" + Display.getHeight());

        int halfX = layoutWidth / 2;
        int halfY = layoutHeight / 2;
System.err.println("sublayout:" + width + "," + height + "; " + halfX + "," + halfY);

        int numberWidth = halfX - number.getMarginLeft() - number.getMarginRight();
        int numberHeight = layoutHeight - number.getMarginTop() - number.getMarginBottom();
        layoutChild(number, numberWidth, numberHeight);
        setPositionChild(number, 0 + number.getMarginLeft(), 0 + number.getMarginTop());
System.err.println(number + " " + numberWidth + "," + numberHeight + " " +number.getMarginLeft());

        int plusWidth = halfX - plus.getMarginLeft() - plus.getMarginRight();
        int plusHeight = halfY - plus.getMarginTop() - plus.getMarginBottom();
        layoutChild(plus, plusWidth, plusHeight);
        setPositionChild( plus, halfX + plus.getMarginLeft(), plus.getMarginTop());

        int minusWidth = halfX - minus.getMarginLeft() - minus.getMarginRight();
        int minusHeight = halfY - minus.getMarginTop() - minus.getMarginBottom();
        layoutChild(minus, minusWidth, minusHeight);
        // Use plus.getMarginHeight() for better alignment.
        setPositionChild( minus, halfX + plus.getMarginLeft(), halfY + minus.getMarginTop() );

        //setVirtualExtent(layoutWidth, height);
        setExtent(layoutWidth, height);
    }

    public EditField getNumberField() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumberField(EditField number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public ButtonField getPlusField() {
        return plus;
    }
    public void setPlusField(ButtonField plus) {
        this.plus = plus;
    }
    public Field getMinusField() {
        return minus;
    }
    public void setMinusField(ButtonField minus) {
        this.minus = minus;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to what you are trying to achieve is

[image]

Few notes:

1. `EditField` always use `USE_ALL_WIDTH`. It doesn't matter if you requested it or not. Therefore, if you want to limit its width you have override its `layout()` method. In my code snippet, its width is limited by the maximum chars allowed for this field's value (see `CustomEditField`).
2. `ButtonField` ignores `USE_ALL_WIDTH` and `USE_ALL_HEIGHT`. Its extent depends only on the text within the button. In order to achieve the effect of `USE_ALL_WIDTH`, you have to add horizontal padding to it.
3. Unfortunately, the padding trick won't work if you want to achieve the USE_ALL_HEIGHT effect. When you add vertical padding to a button, at some stage it will repeat its background vertically. If it is required, you will have to write a custom button field for it.

Also check **BlackBerry's advanced UI components** [at this page](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276).

Here is the code:

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Font;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FontMetrics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.XYEdges;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.EditField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.Border;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.BorderFactory;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.text.NumericTextFilter;

public class NumberClicker extends Manager {

    private class CustomEditField extends EditField {
        public int getPreferredWidth() {
            FontMetrics fontMetrics = new FontMetrics();
            getFont().getMetrics(fontMetrics);
            return getMaxSize()*fontMetrics.getMaxCharWidth();
        };

        public int getPreferredHeight() {
            // forcing the field to be single lined
            return getFont().getHeight();
        }

        protected void layout(int width, int height) {
            super.layout(
                Math.min(width, getPreferredWidth()),
                Math.min(height, getPreferredHeight())
            );
        }
    }

    final XYEdges MARGINS = new XYEdges(2,2,2,2);

    EditField _number;
    Manager _numberManager;

    ButtonField _plus;
    ButtonField _minus;


    public NumberClicker() {
        super(0);

        Font font = getFont();
        font = font.derive(Font.BOLD, font.getHeight() + 10);
        _number = new CustomEditField();
        _number.setFilter(new NumericTextFilter());
        _number.setMaxSize(1);
        _number.setFont(font);
        setValue(1);

        _numberManager = new Manager(0) {
            protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {           
                layoutChild(_number, width, height);
                setPositionChild(_number, 
                    Math.max(0, (width - _number.getWidth())/2), 
                    Math.max(0, (height - _number.getHeight())/2)
                );
                setExtent(width, height);
            }
        };

        _numberManager.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(new XYEdges()));
        _numberManager.setMargin(MARGINS);
        _numberManager.add(_number);
        add(_numberManager);

        _plus = new ButtonField("+", 0);
        _plus.setMargin(MARGINS);
        add(_plus);

        _minus = new ButtonField("-");
        _minus.setMargin(MARGINS);
        add(_minus);

        _plus.setRunnable(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                increment();
            }           
        });

        _minus.setRunnable(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                decrement();
            }           
        });
    }

    private void increment() {
        synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) { //probably not needed here. overkill.
            _number.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(_number.getText().trim()) + 1));
        }
    }

    private void decrement() {
        if (Integer.parseInt(_number.getText()) <= 0) {
            return;
        }

        synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) { //probably not needed here. overkill.
            _number.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(_number.getText().trim()) - 1));
        }
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        if (value < 0) {
            return;
        }

        synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) { // MUST. can be called from non UI thread.
            _number.setText(Integer.toString(value));
        }
    }

    /** 
     * Compute sizes and positions of subfields.
     */
    public void sublayout(int width, int height)  {
        int heightUsed = 0;
        int halfX = width / 2;

        Border border = _plus.getBorder();
        int plusWidth = halfX - _plus.getMarginLeft() - _plus.getMarginRight();
        int plusHeight = height - _plus.getMarginTop() - _plus.getMarginBottom();

        // calculate horizontal padding so the button will look like USE_ALL_WIDTH
        int plusHPadding = (Math.max(0, plusWidth - _plus.getPreferredWidth() - border.getLeft() - border.getRight()))/2;
        _plus.setPadding(0, plusHPadding, 0, plusHPadding);

        layoutChild(_plus, plusWidth, plusHeight);
        setPositionChild( _plus, halfX + _plus.getMarginLeft(), _plus.getMarginTop());
        heightUsed += _plus.getHeight() + _plus.getMarginTop() + _plus.getMarginBottom();

        border = _minus.getBorder();
        int minusWidth = halfX - _minus.getMarginLeft() - _minus.getMarginRight();
        int minusHeight = height - _plus.getHeight() - _minus.getMarginTop() - _minus.getMarginBottom();

        // calculate horizontal padding so the button will look like USE_ALL_WIDTH
        int minusHPadding = (Math.max(0, minusWidth - _minus.getPreferredWidth() - border.getLeft() - border.getRight()))/2; 
        _minus.setPadding(0, minusHPadding, 0, minusHPadding);

        layoutChild(_minus, minusWidth, minusHeight);
        setPositionChild( _minus, halfX + _plus.getMarginLeft(), heightUsed + _minus.getMarginTop());
        heightUsed += _minus.getHeight() + _minus.getMarginTop() + _minus.getMarginBottom();

        int numberWidth = halfX - _numberManager.getMarginLeft() - _numberManager.getMarginRight();
        int numberHeight = heightUsed - _numberManager.getMarginTop() - _numberManager.getMarginBottom();
        layoutChild(_numberManager, numberWidth, numberHeight);
        setPositionChild(_numberManager, _numberManager.getMarginLeft(), _numberManager.getMarginTop());

        setExtent(width, heightUsed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I thought it would involve complexities of the various components. Will be glad when we have a consistent, reasonably complete, and more predictable GUI API to use, but sad it won't be Java based (at least not on the BlackBerry platform).